# ¿Como crear apropiadamente Objetos en Java dinamicamente?

Tags: java

Necesito crear cantidad de componentes n lo que no se es, si este apropiadamente escrito la forma en que lo hago

```
public class cualquierClase{
private JTextArea textAreaTab;

private JTextArea createTextAreaTab(int row, int col, String nameTextArea){
    textAreaTab = new JTextArea(row, col);
    textAreaTab.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textAreaTab.setSize(200, 250);
    textAreaTab.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreaTab.setForeground(Color.blue);
    textAreaTab.setEditable(false);
    textAreaTab.setName("textAreaTab_"+nameTextArea);
    if (iteradorDePrueba("textAreaTab_"+nameTextArea)) {
        boxes.add(textAreaTab);
    }
    return textAreaTab;
}

}
```

Al superar el if se guardara en una lista en la cual los estoy almacenando.

lo que me genera duda es si:
¿cada vez que llame el metodo se creara un Objeto nuevo y lo guardara en memoria de todas forma asi no supere el if?.

Comment: ponelo como respuesta @Lcop

Comment: @gbianchi listo puesto como respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es guardado en la lista pero si es devuelto, lo que indica que posiblemente si sera guardado en memoria dependiendo de quien lo reciba, adicional los objetos de interfaz normalmente requieren un manejo  especial porque no liberan su memoria con solo GC

Comment: el if evita que hayan objetos duplicados en la lista , ¿Como hago para destruirlos o eliminarlos ?  return null; , servira?

Comment: El problema esta en el hecho de devolverlo, ignoro quien lo recibe, por ende no se que pasa con el objeto, con igualarlo a null debería ser suficiente

Comment: Otro punto fuera de la pregunta esta en que la instancia de objeto que declara, siempre sobreescribe ese textarealab